# Form authentication for . NET sites using Perl

Tags: forms, perl, authentication, mechanize, lwp

We are new in Perl scripting and we wanted to pass through a .NET site authentication. 
We have an existing code for authentication specific for Sharepoint sites, code snippet below:

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent('keep_alive' => '1');
print "$url \n";
$ua->credentials("$uname", "$pwd");
my $response =$ua->get($url);
my $cde = $response->code();
```

We wanted to customize the code so that it will work specific for .NET sites authentication. We used WWW::Mechanize, see code snippet below:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_name('Login');
$mech->field("UserName", $username);
$mech->field("Password", $password);
$mech->click();
```

But when the program is run, an error is shown: "There is no form named 'Login' in sample.pl". Any thoughts on how to authenticate forms specific for .NET sites?

Adding: HTML form code snippet...

```
<div id="loginArea">        
        <div id="loginMessage" class="groupMargin">Sign in with your account</div>
        <form method="post" id="Login" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate" onkeypress="if (event &amp;&amp; event.keyCode
== 13) Login.submitLoginRequest();" action="">
            <div id="formsAuthenticationArea">
                <div id="userNameArea">
                    <input id="userNameInput" name="UserName" type="email" value="" tabindex="1" class="text fullWidth" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">     
                </div>
                <div id="passwordArea">
                     <input id="passwordInput" name="Password" type="password" tabindex="2" class="text fullWidth" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">                            

                </div>
                <div id="kmsiArea" style="display:none">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Kmsi" id="kmsiInput" value="true" tabindex="3">
                    <label for="kmsiInput">Keep me signed in</label>
                </div>
                <div id="submissionArea" class="submitMargin">
                    <span id="submitButton" class="submit" tabindex="4" onkeypress="if (event &amp;&amp; event.keyCode == 32) Login.submitLoginRequest();" onclick="return Login.submitLoginRequest();">Sign in</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this code works for .NET sites:

```
$mech->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        login => "somelogin",
        pass  => "somepass",
    },
    button => "submit_button_name",
);
```

But you have weird error message: you're selecting "Login" form but `$mech` searching for "loginForm"... Can you show actual form's HTML?

Also there is no need to do `$mech->cookie_jar(...)` because `$mech` do this by default.

**UPDATE**
Try this code (`Login` is `id` of your form but not the `name`):

```
$mech->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        UserName => "somelogin",
        Password  => "somepass",
    },
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this @gangabass. Sorry, I am not able to post a screenshot of the actual form since I am new to stackoverflow, and I don't have enough reputation points. The login form is just like the typical login forms you can see over the web: Two text fields for the UserName and Password. And a button named, "Sign On". 

I also edited the error message, form name to 'Login'.

Comment: @Charli I talked about HTML code of the form not it's screenshot.

Comment: Would it be okay if I post just a code snippet of the HTML  form?

Comment: @Charli yes, this is all I need

Comment: Hi @gangbass, I've added the HTML form code snippet in the original question I had above since it's too long to post it here.

Comment: We have another question, relating to going through the Login page. Since we are unable to go through the Login page, we tried using _‘require "$mech.pm"; ‘_ just before the $mech->submit_form(…..); But after running the code, we received this error message: **‘WWW::Mechanize=HASH(0x3812504).pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at ADS.pl line 44, <$input> line 1.’** Do we need to have an installer for this to be able to make a successful run? Or any other options?